# Importing custom objects in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, dae, collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i made my custom objects in 3d studio max and now i want it to be shown in my gazebo world at specific place. Any suggestions which is the best and easy way to achieve it.
i was looking [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/42529/how-to-import-collada-dae-files-into-gazebo-rosfuerte/) but doesnt work for me.

thanks
(p.s i am using ros Electric and ubuntu 10.04)
[its SOLVED no more interested in answer thanks]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43867/importing-custom-objects-in-gazebo/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suppose your model will be in .3ds format. I suggest you follow this procedure.

- Convert to .dae or .stl using [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) (or any software). I prefer converting to .stl using MeshLab
- In the  or  tag of your model file specify the size of the bounding box (or cylinder or sphere).
- Specify the pose of bounding box in your world through  and
- If you are using .stl specify the material in  (beware of materials available on fuerte)

Find a sample file in [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls) (named table.urdf)

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-09-16**:
Thanks prasana.